# Spliting 2D array into sections

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

For a task in my Algorithms and Data Structures lecture I need to find a way to split a given 2D array into sections. Here is a example:
The program is gets a Integer `k>0` at the start. The arrays size is `[k*k]x[k*k]` For `k=3` it would be something like:

```
2  2  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  
1  0  1  2  1  0  1  0  0  
1  1  1  0  1  2  1  1  2  
2  2  2  2  2  0  0  2  0  
0  0  0  1  1  2  2  1  2  
1  2  2  1  2  0  0  0  1  
0  1  0  1  0  0  2  1  1  
2  1  0  1  0  2  2  2  2  
1  0  1  2  2  2  2  1  2
```

I now want to view the array as sections of size `k*k`:

```
2  2  0    1  0  0    0  1  1    
1  0  1    2  1  0    1  0  0    
1  1  1    0  1  2    1  1  2    

2  2  2    2  2  0    0  2  0    
0  0  0    1  1  2    2  1  2    
1  2  2    1  2  0    0  0  1    

0  1  0    1  0  0    2  1  1    
2  1  0    1  0  2    2  2  2    
1  0  1    2  2  2    2  1  2
```

My task now is to add the integers of each segment und store them in an array of size `k*k`. For now I have failed miserably getting only wrong outputs. Is there a trick to this or some kind of library which features such a functionality?

Comment: Can you post your solution you have come up so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
int[][] result = new int[k][k];
for (int i = 0; i < k * k; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < k * k; j++) {
        result[i / k][j / k] += array[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I cam up with so far. I think I messed up the loops:

```java
private static ArrayList<Integer> getPathZij() {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int k = (int) Math.sqrt(map.length);
    for (int v = k; v < map.length; v = v + k) {
        for (int i = v - k; i < v; i++) {
            int value = 0;
            for (int j = v - k; j < v; j++) {
                value = value + map[i][j];
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```